# Get access_token for a "secret" Facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a Facebook group that has the privacy set to "secret". I'm wondering if it's possible to use the Facebook Graph API to obtain every YouTube link posted to the group page.

From what I've read so far I need to get an access_token for the group which I'm having troubles understanding how to obtain. I see a lot of articles on getting the access_token of a user but I'm not sure how that would work with a group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to request the "user_groups" and "friends_groups" permission in order to access these secret group.

To do that, just add the two permission strings in the scope parameter when requesting an access token, e.g.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,user_groups,friends_groups
```

Reference: [Facebook Graph API Documentation - Group](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/)

Comment: In case that's not clear, you'll need the access token of a user who can see the group

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you need to be admin of the secret group. user_managed_groups means groups that you manage.